# How do I use this column in a SOQL join?

Tags: soql, query, inner-join

I'm trying to write a JOIN in SOQL.  But having some problems.  I have a column

```
PLWorkshopProduct__c
```

in my table that links to another table, Product2.  I tried writing the below ..

```
Select ID FROM CventSession__c WHERE PLWorkshopProduct__c IN (Select Id from Product2 WHERE IsActive = True)
```

but get the error

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: The left operand field in the where expression for outer query should be an id field, cannot use: 'PLWorkshopProduct__c'
```

What's the proper way to write a join in this case?

Comment: As the error states, you are trying to find `PLWorkshopProduct__c` in list of Product Ids. It expects `PLWorkshopProduct__c` to be a `Product2.Id` What is your data type for `PLWorkshopProduct__c`?

Comment: PLWorkshopProduct__c is a string that has the same value somethign in the Product2.Id table.  At least when I select it, it looks like a stirng in as far as it has a bunch of letters and numbers.

Comment: You will need to verify if `PLWorkshopProduct__c` on `CventSession__c` is of type Lookup to Product, to be able to execute this query?

Comment: I'm really inexperienced with SF, how do I do what you just said I need to do ?

Comment: I will recommend you take some trailhead on this topic, [this is a good place](https://sforce.co/2H35Bne) to start with. In summary it seems that the field here is not an Id field and thus you are getting the error. Adding the details about the field type and also how you are executing this query will help anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Whats the point of bounty when battery - cord answered it.

Comment: Yeah, Ill gladly edit my answer. Not sure why you didn't comment asking for clarification or changes. Are you running the query in a context outside of apex, where you can't use the code-based solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You have to move the query in the filter outside of the soql. Apex is smart enough to change the type of an id between string and id, but not inside soql - you get a nasty error instead.

However, if you get those same ids, inside a list of ids, and use that, then it preforms perfectly. Heres an example:

```
// Lookup your records from your filter query 
// put them into a map so we can get their ids easily 
Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> items = new Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>([
    SELECT Id 
    FROM OpportunityLineItem 
    WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
]);

// Use the variable in your query instead of your subquery 
System.debug([
    SELECT Id, Plain_Text_Id__c 
    FROM Custom_Object__c 
    WHERE Plain_Text_Id__c IN :items.keySet()
]);

// Uses a list of Ids to find matches in a text field - acts like id match
```

---

Only solution I could think of that didn't involve apex (which I think is the missing link here, you need a solution that fits into a join, not something that needs code) was to make a field `Text_Id__c`, which returns a text version of the records id, but trying to use this field results in:

> semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use: 'Text_Id__c'

```
Select ID 
FROM Some_Object__c 
WHERE Product__c IN 
(Select Text_Id__c from Product WHERE IsActive = True)
```

Since both have to be an id field, and soql doesn't do casting for you, you need to create a new lookup, or convert your existing field over to a lookup, in order to get this join to work without apex.

Comment: There is a distinct performance hit in taking this approach - the lookup field is indexed, but the string field isn't.

Comment: I'm not advocating for using text based lookups, but some objects (LineItem2) aren't able to be used in lookup fields. "Products" aren't, but the OP hasn't provided any other information aside from "I have a text field I need to find ids in".

Comment: no argument there, but it seems sensible to point out the pitfalls of such an approach. Perhaps you can amend your answer?

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons I recommend you modify your schema to convert the "PLWorkshopProduct__c" field's type to be Lookup to Product2 instead of trying to use the value of this field as a (non-indexed) filter.

Comment: I don't have the ability to do that.  I have to work with what's there.

Comment: Could you add a second field, a lookup, that gets populated in a trigger when the PLWorkshopProduct__c field's value changes by simply casting the string to an ID, then use that second field instead?